# Combining different SVM models

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I'm creating a character recognition software in Python using scikit-learn. I have a large dataset of images labelled [A-Za-z]. I'm using linear SVM. Training the model using all the samples with 52 different labels is very, very slow.

If I divide my training dataset in 13 sections such that each section has images of only 4 characters, and no image can be a part of more than 1 section, and then train 13 different models.

How can I combine those models together to create a more accurate model? OR if I perform classification of test set on all 13 models and compare individual sample's result on basis of confidence score (selecting the one with with highest score), will it affect the accuracy of the overall model?

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you need to to is some kind of Order Reduction of data.
After the order reduction classify data into in 13 large group and then do a final classification tool.

I would look into [Linear Discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) for the first step I mentioned.